# Что такое CRTP?

Tags: c++

Что такое curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)? Когда его использовать?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Comment: http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/26/crtp_demystified.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) (примерный перевод: Странно рекурсивный шаблон проектирования или Странно повторяющийся паттерн) — идиома языка C++, состоящая в том, что некоторый класс X наследуется от шаблона класса, использующего X как шаблонный параметр.

Пример:

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template<class T>
class Base
{
    // methods within Base can use template to access members of Derived
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

Используется для статического полиморфизма:

```
template <class T> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        // ...
        static_cast<T*>(this)->implementation();
        // ...
    }

    static void static_func()
    {
        // ...
        T::static_sub_func();
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
    static void static_sub_func();
};
```

Источник: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score -2):

Что же из себя представляет CRTP? CRTP можно описать буквально в одном предложении: CRTP моделирует ситуацию при которой класс-наследник наследует класс-родитель параметризированный классом-наследником.